# MediaLibrary Nova about table "Media" in DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

**I have this code:**

```
class Models extends Model implements HasMedia
{

    use HasMediaTrait;
```

When I have used it, in my DB table "media" was created automatically and
it contains the downloaded files.
That table "media", like I understand, refers to library MediaLibrary.

**Can I change table Media? Can I detes from table media to use in another table, which I'll create?**